# Guardar video grabado en opencv

Tags: python, opencv

tengo el siguiente codigo para grabar un video con opencv, pero cuando termino la grabacion e intento abrir el archivo creado, me sale un error de formato en el reproductor, tambien me aparece el siguiente error en la consola:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```
import cv2

captura=cv2.VideoCapture(0)

ancho= int(captura.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH))
altura= int(captura.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH))

codigo=cv2.VideoWriter_fourcc(*'MP4V')
grabador=cv2.VideoWriter('video.avi', codigo, 20, (ancho, altura))

while True:
    resultado, video= captura.read()

    #grabar
    grabador.write(video)    

    cv2.imshow('Nuestro video', video)
    if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF== ord('q'):
        break

captura.release()
grabador.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Comment: me lo guarda el video pero sigue dandome error en el reproductor al intentar abrirlo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tres apuntes:

- Estás especificando el código incorrecto para el codec si quieres usar un contenedor avi, debe ser `XVID` y no `MP4V`.
- Tienes un error al especificar el alto del video, debe ser:

  ```
  altura = int(captura.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT))
  ```
- Es buena idea comprobar que la lectura de cada frame ha sido correcta con un condicional sobre `resultado`.

El código podría quedar:

```
import cv2



captura = cv2.VideoCapture(0)

ancho = int(captura.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH))
alto = int(captura.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT))

codec = cv2.VideoWriter_fourcc(*'XVID')
grabador = cv2.VideoWriter('video.avi', codec, 20, (ancho, alto))

while True:
    resultado, frame = captura.read()
    # grabar
    if resultado:
        grabador.write(frame)
        cv2.imshow('Nuestro video', frame)
    else:
        break

    if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
        break

captura.release()
grabador.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Comment: gracias el 3 er punto no era necesario el problema estaba en el cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT